# How to centre tooltip on jquery ui-slider

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using the jquery ui-slider to which I've added a tooltip.

Here's how it looks:

[image]

The tooltip is added by inserting a DIV inside the slider handle.

```
function sliderCreate(desc) {

    var tooltip = $('<div class="ui-slider-tooltip">' + desc + '</div>');

    $(this).find('.ui-slider-handle').append(tooltip);
}
```

As you can see the tooltip is currently aligned to the left hand handle edge. This is a problem when the handle is moved to the right hand side of the slider.

```
.ui-slider-tooltip
{
    .BorderRadius(0.3rem);
    background-color:@dkBlueBG;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:1;
    padding:0.3rem;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:2.9rem;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

I'm looking to either:

- centre the tooltip to reduce the overhang;
- move the position of the tooltip as the slider is moved past the halfway mark (align it to the right hand edge)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please create a jsFiddle or add a code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center the tooltip...

```
.ui-slider-tooltip
{
    .BorderRadius(0.3rem);
    background-color:@dkBlueBG;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:1;
    padding:0.3rem;
    position:absolute;

    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%); /* add your prefixes as required */

    bottom:2.9rem;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

To move the position of the tooltip as the slider is moved past the halfway mark (align it to the right hand edge) would require additional JS/JQ to determine whether the slider value is greater than 50% and then change the CSS.